# Edit Multiple Files Simultaneously in VS Code / Cursors Across Multiple Files

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have two copies of a file side by side in split view and I want to add cursors in both to edit the code at the same time à la Sublime, is there any route to accomplish this?